# IOS Update 9 crash calabash

Tags: ruby, xcode, calabash-ios

After updating the xcode for version 7, the calabash no longer meets my simulator, returning the error:

> No matching processes belonging to you were found
>
> Unable to find application named 'iOS Simulator'

This error started after the update

Xcode version : Version 7.0 (7A220)

Calabash version : 0.16.3

Ruby Version :2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005)

Comment: Could you please show the command(s) you are executing in the terminal please?

Answer (score 1):

That seems like you aren't actually using Calabash 0.16.3.

The name and location of the simulator application changes with the Xcode version.  "iOS Simulator" is the name of the Xcode 6 simulator application?

Are you using a Gemfile and bundler?  Do you have other calabash-cucumber version installed?

Can you please paste the exact command you are trying to execute?

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Updating-your-run-loop-version

Comment: I've solved this problem, i got other problem with simulator, when simulator. The simulator reset aways i execute run

Comment: I am not going to answer your question in a comment.  Please describe what you did to solve your original problem and mark my answer as accepted (correct).  Ask your next question in another post. https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki#reporting-problems